# Guidance to set python environment on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I'm trying to run my python scripts from the windows command line.

*Example: cygwin> PYTHONPATH=dir1:dir2 python script.py param1 param2*

I already do that from Ubuntu's command line with no issues. 
On Windows, however, I've been unable to achieve it. On a particular script, Python claims that it can't import _AES, but pycrypto is installed, and the script runs perfectly fine from pycharm:

from cygwin:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=.:../..:/cygdrive/c/Python27/Lib/site-packages/ ./decrypt_tclaves.py Param1 Param2 Param3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./decrypt_tclaves.py", line 29, in <module>
    from encrypted_tables import unpack_tclaves
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/ItaloMunoz/Documents/Dev/Autentia6/server/autentia_db/encrypted_tables.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
  File "/cygdrive/c/Python27/Lib/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 50, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import _AES
ImportError: cannot import name _AES

$ pip install pycrypto
Requirement already satisfied: pycrypto in c:\python27\lib\site-packages

$ echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\\\n/g' | grep -i python
/cygdrive/c/Python27\
/cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts/\
```

I thought of a permission issue, so I ran the command below, but the issue keeps the same:

> ```
> $chmod 777 -R /cygdrive/c/Python27/Lib/site-packages/
> ```

I've also tried pycharm's command line with the same bad result (again, from cygwin):

```
$ PYTHONPATH=.:../..:/cygdrive/c/Python27/Lib/site-packages/ python "C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.3\\helpers\\pydev\\pydev_run_in_console.py" 52333 52334 C:/Users/ItaloMunoz/Documents/Dev/Autentia6/server/autentia_db/decrypt_tclaves.py Param1 Param2 Param3
Running C:/Users/ItaloMunoz/Documents/Dev/Autentia6/server/autentia_db/decrypt_tclaves.py
PyDev console: starting.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_run_in_console.py", line 78, in <module>
    globals = run_file(file, None, None)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_run_in_console.py", line 35, in run_file
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:/Users/ItaloMunoz/Documents/Dev/Autentia6/server/autentia_db/decrypt_tclaves.py", line 29, in <module>
    from encrypted_tables import unpack_tclaves
  File "C:/Users/ItaloMunoz/Documents/Dev/Autentia6/server/autentia_db/encrypted_tables.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
  File "/cygdrive/c/Python27/Lib/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 50, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import _AES
ImportError: cannot import name _AES
```

from cmd:

The issue seems worst, because 'autentia_common' is pointed by %PYTHONPATH% (second directory in PYTHONPATH: ..\..)

```
$set | findstr /i "pythonpath"
PYTHONPATH=.:..\..

$python decrypt_tclaves.py Param1 Param2 Param3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decrypt_tclaves.py", line 28, in <module>
    from autentia_common import log
ImportError: No module named autentia_common
```

Output from pycharm on Windows:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/ItaloMunoz/Documents/Dev/Autentia6/server/autentia_db/decrypt_tclaves.py Param1 Param2 Param3
0035303233352a5c345e6a642f226c640930272665d1e7773e402823225f61
0035303233352a5c345e6a642f226c640930272665d1e7773e402823225f6100
31345a2e6f722b37342d265cd1e76c643065773e40280923225f5e6a61272631
31345a2e6f722b37342d265cd1e76c643065773e40280923225f5e6a61272631... (more output here)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So, What am I missing? Any guidance will be very much appreciated, thanks!

Note: Using python 2.7. It's the only installed interpreter

Comment: don't  mix environments native windows and cygwin; please note, that from cygwin you have called native windows python and it not see cygwin variables. Use powershell or cmd.exe instead of cygwin

Comment: And on native Windows to separate paths in environment variables, use `;` instead of `:`

Comment: None of Python's standard directories such as "site-packages" should ever be added to `PYTHONPATH`. Secondly, you cannot using cygwin paths in Windows Python. It has no idea what "/cygdrive/c/path" is; use "C:\path". Also, the delimiter in Windows environment variables is semicolon, not colon. As to environment variables, I'm pretty sure it is wrong to say you can't pass them from a cygwin program; cygwin programs are Windows programs that link with cygwin's POSIX library; they have a PEB and environment block that can be inherited normally.

Comment: As to `_AES`, it appears the version of Python you're running doesn't have this extension module installed. Make a careful inspection of every Python you have installed, printing `sys.executable` to note where it's located and whether `import _AES` succeeds.

Comment: Thank you @Reishin

Comment: Thanks @eryksun. It looks like I just can't use cygwin because of the POSIX-like filenames injected into windows-python. Regarding cmd, .... silly mistake: changing PATH separator made it work!